# How to catch a corrupted or not accessible java sql query output

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a java program that accepts an SQL query. It has a try catch function in case the table name has an invalid name/special characters, not found in database, or I/O exception. I'm wondering is there any way I can catch a corrupted output or not accessible data after the query?

Here's my current implementation:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table + "';";
        try {
            conn = ConnDelegation.supplyConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(!rs.next()) {
                rCode.setValue(MSG_CATALOG_ENTRY_NOT_FOUND);
            } else {
                try {
                    rCode.setValue(MSG_OPERATION_SUCCESSFUL);
                }catch (SQLException e) {
                    rCode.setValue(MSG_CATALOG_NOT_ACCESSIBLE);
                }
            }
            
        }catch (SQLException e) {

            rCode.setValue(MSG_PARAMLIST_IO_ERROR);
        }
```

I assumed that if the data was found but has an issue/error, that was the correct time to catch. But I'm hoping to have a specific error code that only specifies on corrupted or non accessible output.

Comment: Hi - doesn't executeQuery return the error reason in SQLException? If it does, why not have a single try/catch statement and process the different error types in the catch? At the moment your code seems to be assuming what the different types of error might be based on the different positions of your various try/catch statements

Comment: This question is about java but you have not tagged java ?